# The document.title is NOT Document <title>

Tags: javascript

ok, this is weird, and I like to have an idea if this is possible

e.g.

the page

`<title>12345</title>`

then if js is `if(document.title=='12345')...`

I guess this must be true, BUT my counter tells me otherwise, 10% is NOT (most in IE)

So I like to know, is there any browser plugin or other stuff does this and make `document.title` is NOT `<title>`

Comment: That should work if the document is formatted properly.  Please include the header portion of the documents that don't work so we can take a look at it.  Be sure to include the doctype declaration portion.

Comment: Make sure that there is no space or some special unicode character or BOM

Comment: Your what tells you otherwise?

Comment: I have to add log of some kind, I have to believe this can happen otherwise I will search problem elsewhere.

Comment: Are there multiple `<title>` elements? Do you have a demo page so that it can be reproduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging what `document.title` is if it isn't `'12345'`.

The most likely thing is if the file is being transferred with chunked encoding (a common feature in HTTP/1.1) then the `<title>` tag may be split in half and this would cause an incorrect title to show up.

This can be fixed by adding:

```
window.onload = function() {document.title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;};
```

Comment: ok, do you mean that title got split to two parts, then it will have a space in the middle if I just directly read `document.title` I think it might be the answer, highly possible. Thanks